# pandas - can't strip '}' by str.strip function

Tags: pandas

i have below sample data in csv file.

```
string,class,id
"{""key1"":""value1"":""key2"":""value2""}",classA,idA
"{""key3"":""value3"":""key4"":""value4""}",classB,idB
...
```

when I use strip function to strip the right brace }, it fails to strip.

```
df.string =  df.string.apply(lambda x: x.strip('}'))
```

but when i tried to strip the left brace {, it works.

what's the root cause here?

Comment: There is some values after `{`, seems here `"`

Comment: This isn't reproducible unless you also post the actual `read.csv` command used to read in the CSV file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you read the file with `doublequote=False`, this should work fine with the default `doublequote=True`?

```
import io

data = '''string,class,id
"{""key1"":""value1"":""key2"":""value2""}",classA,idA
"{""key3"":""value3"":""key4"":""value4""}",classB,idB'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep=',', doublequote=True)

df['string'] = df['string'].str.strip('}')

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                             string   class   id
0  {"key1":"value1":"key2":"value2"  classA  idA
1  {"key3":"value3":"key4":"value4"  classB  idB
```

Comment: doublequote=True , this resolve the issue. thanks